# How to use linq to paginate a SortedList in Ascending or Descending order

Tags: c#, linq, pagination

This does what I want:

```
if (order == SortOrder.Ascending) {
    return list.Values.Skip(pageIndex * numberPerPage).Take(numberPerPage);
} else if (order == SortOrder.Descending) {
    return list.Values.Reverse().Skip(pageIndex * numberPerPage).Take(numberPerPage);
}
```

However, I don't want to have to reverse the list every time this is called, I could write a for loop that goes through the list backwards and implement the paging myself, but im looking for a simple way to get this done with linq.

Comment: I think you need to show the declaration/datatypes for list and list.Values.

Comment: The list is simple: SortedList<ListKey, IArchiveKey> list;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to storing the "sorted" list (calling `Reverse` really just creates a backwards iterator, it doesn't re-sort).  You don't have to use `Skip` if you don't want to.

For example, if you are always showing Page 1, then Page 2, then page 3, you can simply use `Take` alone:

```
// done when user clicks something to change `order`
orderedEnumerator = order == SortOrder.Ascending ? list : list.Reverse();
//...
foreach(var e in orderedEnumerator.Take(pageSize)
{
// show first page
}
foreach(var e in orderedEnumerator.Take(pageSize)
{
// show second page
}
foreach(var e in orderedEnumerator.Take(pageSize)
{
// show third page
}
```

The actual `foreach` code could be the same block of code simply executed at different times, eg:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> GetCurrentPage()
{
    return orderedEnumerator.Take(pageSize);
}

public void nextPageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(var e in GetCurrentPage())
   {
      // elements in current page
   }
}
```

Comment: This assumes they're moving pages sequentially, but yes.

Comment: I had my suspicions Reverse() would create a backwards iterator, thanks for this info, exactly what I needed.

Comment: More info can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx e.g.: "Unlike OrderBy, this sorting method does not consider the actual values themselves in determining the order. Rather, it just returns the elements in the reverse order from which they are produced by the underlying source."

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas.

1. Reverse the list only once when they change the sorting order. Then just call the pagination normally:

   ```
   SortOrder oldOrder = SortOrder.Ascending;

   void SetSortOrder(SortOrder newOrder)
   {
       if(oldOrder != newOrder)
       {
           list.Values = list.Values.Reverse().ToList();
           oldOrder = newOrder;
       }
   }

   IEnumerable<Stuff> GetPage(int pageIndex, int numberPerPage, SortOrder order)
   {
       SetSortOrder(order);
       return list.Values.Skip(pageIndex * numberPerPage).Take(numberPerPage);
   }
   ```
2. Keep an ascending *and* descending list in memory:

   ```
   List<Stuff> ascendingList, descendingList;

   void SetLists()
   {
       ascendingList = list.Values;
       descendingList = list.Values.Reverse().ToList();
   }

   IEnumerable<Stuff> GetPage(int pageIndex, int numberPerPage, SortOrder order)
   {
       return (order == SortOrder.Ascending ? ascendingList : descendingList).Skip(pageIndex * numberPerPage).Take(numberPerPage);
   }
   ```

Comment: Neither of these solutions are as efficient as a for loop, I'm looking for something as efficient but easier to write and read.